# PostgreSQL index for jsonb @> search

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT "survey_results".* FROM "survey_results" WHERE (raw @> '{"client":{"token":"test_token"}}');
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns following results:

```
 Seq Scan on survey_results  (cost=0.00..352.68 rows=2 width=2039) (actual time=132.942..132.943 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (raw @> '{"client": {"token": "test_token"}}'::jsonb)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2133
 Planning time: 0.157 ms
 Execution time: 132.991 ms
(5 rows)
```

I want to add index on `client` key inside `raw` field so search will be faster. I don't know how to do it. When I add index for whole `raw` column like this:

```
CREATE INDEX test_index on survey_results USING GIN (raw);
```

then everything works as expected. I don't want to add index for whole `raw` because I have a lot of records in database and I do not want to increase its size.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JSON objects as atm in the example then you can specify index only `client` like that:

```
CREATE INDEX test_client_index ON survey_results USING GIN (( raw->'client ));
```

But since you are using `@>` operator in your query then in your case it might make sense to create index only for that operator like that:

```
CREATE INDEX test_client_index ON survey_results USING GIN (raw jsonb_path_ops);
```

See more from documentation about [Postgres JSONB indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING):